# Socket.io only work sometimes and is sharing emit

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, socket.io, functional-programming

I've requests loops to API where I use data from the first request to make other request. When I finish the last request i emit data to front-end then show as requests are finish. It works perfectly sometimes but other times the requests are made but doesn't emit to front-end. Also if you open new tab while requests are made its emit to the first tab. I need to send results in individual tabs.

server.js

```
var server = https.createServer(httpOptions, app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
app.io = io;
  io.once('connection', function(socket){
  app.socket = socket.id;
  socket.on("disconnect",function(){    
    socket.disconnect();
  });
});
```

results.js (Request route)

```
const auth = require("../services/auth");
const rp = require("request-promise")
exports.get = async(req, res, next)=>{
    var i= 0;
    var x = 0;
    const buyerName = []
    const itemID = []
    res.render("sales",{username: data.name})

        rp("URI 1") // VERY FIRST GET AND CALL LOOP
        .then(body => {
            callNext(body)
        })
        .catch(e => {
            console.log(e)
        })


    function callNext(body) {
        let responseJSON = JSON.parse(body);
        if (x>=responseJSON.results.length) { // VERIFY LOOP INDEX TO CALL END FUNCTION
            reqProductsEnd();
        } else {
            rp("URI 2")
            .then(data =>{
                const order = JSON.parse(data)
                buyerName.push(order.buyer.nickname)
                reqProducts(body)
            })
            .catch(e=>{
                console.log(+e)
            })

        }
    }

    function reqProducts(body) {
            rp("URI 3",{
                data: x++
            })
            .then(data =>{
                const item = JSON.parse(data)
                itemID.push(item.thumbnail)
                req.app.io.to(`${req.app.socket}`).emit('receive item', {buyer: buyerName[i], itemID: itemID[i]});
                console.log(i)
                console.log(productName[i])
                i++;
                callNext(body) // CALL LOOP AGAIN
            })
            .catch(e=>{
                console.log(e)
            })       
}
    function reqProductsEnd() {
        console.log(itemID)
        console.log(buyerName)
    }   
}
```

view.ejs

```
$(function () {
var socket = io.connect('https://localhost:3000', { forceNew: true });
socket.on('receive item', function(msg){
    var x = JSON.stringify(msg);
    $("div").append(msg.buyerName);
});
});
```

Comment: `app.socket = socket.id;`  That doesn't make sense, the socket you have here is between server & client, and of course this is not a singleton.

Comment: I dont know how i can get socket id in express route except this way

Comment: You can't,  there is no link between a `request / response`, and a `socket`.  If you want a link you might be best sending the express session id to the connected socket.  If you just want send a message to all clients, don't use the socket from connection, but the main socket.  `io.sockets.emit`

Comment: I need to send to a specific client. I want to know if what I intend to do is possible. I mean, send emit every time a request is made.